# Mutable field structure in Haskell without Lens

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that generates a structure
that has fields of mutable values.

Originally, I wrote in TypeScript and the code is as follows:

```
const Foo = <A>(a: A) =>
  ({
    x: a,             //mutable
    y: someFunction   //mutable
  });
```

Basically, the type of `x` is always `A`, and `y` is `A -> A` even they are mutable.

I just need a simple setter and getter function to mutate the fields, and preferably want to use just ST-monad and don't want to depend on libraries such as [Lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

The closest thing I've found so far is ST mutable array [Data.Array.MArray](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html), but this one is for arrays not structures.

What is simple smart approach do you recommend?

Comment: Note that the most important features of the `lens` librariy have little to do with its heavy dependencies. The heart of it is little more than a couple of transparent signatures. [`microlens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens) (ir [its batteries-included version](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens-platform)) is sufficient for about 80% of use cases, while being a much lighter dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a structure like:

```
data Foo a = Foo {
    bar :: a,
    qux :: a -> a
}
```

then you can for example define an object:

```
myFoo :: Foo Int
myFoo = Foo 2 id
```

and create a slighlty modified copy with:

```
myFoo2 :: Foo Int
myFoo2 = myFoo { bar = 4 }
```

so you can use that in an [**`STRef`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-STRef.html#t:STRef) to work with a reference that is updated then with [**`modifySTRef`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-STRef.html#v:modifySTRef), for example:

```
myST :: ST s (Foo Int)
myST = do
    ref <- newSTRef (Foo 2 id)
    modifySTRef ref (\x -> x { bar = 4 })
    readSTRef ref
```

and you can thus run this with `runST myST`. We can for example print the `bar` after evaluating the `ST s (Foo Int)`:

```
ghci> print (bar (runST myST))
4
```